# Vue.js Passed props are undefined in any scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, single-page-application, prop

I am doing single page application writing style to build my app with vue.
However the prop data passed to a child component is not being loaded any scope(created(), mounted() etc).

router/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Ques from '@/components/timeline/Ques'
import Timeline from '@/components/Timeline'

Vue.use(Router);


export default new Router({
 mode: 'history',
 routes: [
   {
     path: '/feeds',
     name: 'Timeline',
     component: Timeline
   },
   {
     path: '/ques',
     name: 'Ques',
     component: Ques
    }
   ]
   })
```

timeline.vue

```
    <template>
    <main class="timeline_wrapper">
    <Ques :timelinePosts="posts"></Ques>
    </main>

    </template>

  <script>
    import Ques from './timeline/Ques.vue'
    export default {
    name: "timeline",
    data() {
      return {
        posts: [
          {
            id: 0,
            name: 'hi'
          },
        ]
      }
     },
   components: { Ques }
   }
</script>
```

Ques.vue

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
     name: "Ques",
     props: [
     'timelinePosts'
     ],
   created () {
     console.log(this.timelinePosts);
   }
  }
</script>
```

what's following the console.log is an error saying the timelinePosts is 'undefined'.
How can the prop value be properly loaded in the child component?

Answer (score 2):

I think is because you have defined Ques in your Router and it doesn't has `props: true`. And i also think that if you are not going to use it from a `<router-link>` you should remove it

Answer (score 1):

I think the name of your property is wrong. Just change in timeline.vue `:timelinePosts="posts"` to `:timeline-posts="posts"`

HTML attribute names are case-insensitive. Any uppercase character will be interpreted as lowercase. So camelCased prop names need to use their kebab-cased equivalents.